# Build a C++ binary w/o dll dependency

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

I wrote some C++ code. I sent it to my friend who isn't a developer. On windows 7 he got the error "the program can't start because msvcr120.dll is missing"

How can I build it so it will run? Do I need to use compile using MSVC 2008? 2005? I'd like this to work on vista+

Comment: [Msvcr120.dll is one of the dynamic link libraries within Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 Redistributable package. So, to download msvcr120.dll file the only thing you need is to visit the official Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013 page and install it on your computer.](http://fixpcnyc.com/msvcr120-dll-is-missing-how-to-download-msvcr120-dll-and-fix-the-error/)

Comment: Direct link to [Visual Studio 2013 C++ Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784) download.

Comment: Hard to guess why you can't google this: Project + Properties, C/C++, Code Generation, Runtime Library = /MT

Comment: Have you tried linking statically? (I haven't with Visual C++ 12.0, but it has worked with earlier versions).

Comment: @Cyber: You missed the point. I want him to run the exe without downloading. I can easily give him the dll and tell him where to put it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you can statically link the run time library using /MT instread of /MD

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kzt1wy3.aspx

Right Click your project -> Properties -> C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Set "Runtime Library" to "/MTd" for debug and "/MT" for release builds

Comment: Short answers are still answers.